# Handling git on a shared user account

Tags: git, commit, root

I'm using `git` to track changes to a series of system configuration file on a server. These files are owned by the `root` account (and for various internal enterprise-y reasons, root is the only account on this box).

There is a central git server, which all changes made on this system are being pushed to.

What I'm trying to do is suppress the warning that `git` throws because there isn't a user account set. What we do is, anyone changing a file under git control simply sets the `--author` option when they do the commit - however, git still complains that the user information isn't set.

For detail, the exact message is:

```
[root@server ~]# git commit --author "Karunamon <karunamon@company.com>"
[master 491d9f8] File updated
 Author: Karunamon <Karunamon@company.com>
 Committer: root <root@server>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

So basically, this is a twofold question:

First, **Is there a way to squelch this warning message?** Setting the config variable is going to end in confusion since there will be a number of people accessing this same repository on this server under the root account.

I did try using the environment variables (`GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, etc), but the same message comes up.

Second, **Is there a better way** (short of some horrid hack involving an .rc file and asking on login) to set the user name and email so that my users don't have to add an `--author` flag to every commit?

The environment variable option would have been perfect - I could just have my users export the variables on login and then they're good until next connect.. but git still whines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
git -c user.email="Karunamon <karunamon@company.com>" commit
```

This will override the config setting when executing that command.

You can then make an `git` alias / wrapper that inserts that value from a local env variable on execution.

Comment: That fails completely: `# git commit -c user.email="Karunamon <karunamon@company.com>"`
`fatal: could not lookup commit user.email=Karunamon <karunamon@company.com>` - It's also even longer than the `author` flag :(

Comment: @MikeyT.K.: Sorry; the word `commit` must come last.  Unlike `--author`, this should suppress the warning.  (I haven't tried it)

Comment: You will need to specify `user.name` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
git -c user.email="karunamon@company.com" -c user.name="Karunamon" commit
```

That one works for me. It requires user.name as well.